# React buttons only show up when using Inspecton page (Chrome and Edge)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx, inspect

I have a progra that retrieves data and then presents a series of problems to solve. The buttons for the problem flow only show up if I put the page into Inspect mode. This happens on both Edge and Chrome. Why is it acting that way, and how do I get it to show normally?

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<html>
    <style>
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Maxwell Cognitive Problem Launcher</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 ID:prob_identifier>ID: 96543210</h1>
        <h2 ID:student_id>1</h2>
    </body>
    
    <div id="maxwell_container"></div>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <div id="feedback"></div>
    <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@svgdotjs/svg.js@3.0/dist/svg.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Load our React component. -->
    <script type="text/babel" src="./maxwell/app/components/MaxwellCore.jsx" crossorigin ></script>
</html>
```

Here is the intro bit:

```
let props = '';
let html_tag = '#maxwell_container';
let student_id = document.getElementById("student_id");
console.log(student_id);
let pg = SVG().addTo(html_tag).viewbox(0,0,10000,5000).size(`100%`, `100%`);
pg.data({'finalAnswer':0});
let stuffout = new ProbProfile(props, pg);
stuffout.getData(pg);
```

Here is the data getting part:

```
class ProbProfile extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, pg)   {
       super(props);
       this.state = {ProbID:'', ProbDesc:'', userID:''};
    }
 
    getData(pg) {
        let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        console.log("Inside getData method");
   
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                // console.log(this.responseText);
                if (this.responseText != '') {
                    let stuff = new Stuff(pg, this.responseText);   
                    problem_page(stuff);
                }
           }
        };
        request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8081/maxwellData', true);
        request.send();
        request.onload;
        //console.log(request.responseText);
    }

    render() {
        return(
        '<div>'+
        '<h2>Getting data</h2>'
            +'{this.getData()}'
        +'</div>'
        );
    }
}
```

And here is where the buttons come in:

```
function problem_page(stuff) {
    const sleep = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
    console.log("Started problem_runner")

    let dbg = 0;
    let inpd = JSON.parse(stuff.stuffout);
    let inpdd = inpd.data;


    const RepeaterWithContinue = () => {
        console.log("Repeater with Continue");
        const evaluateRef = React.useRef(false);
        const continueRef = React.useRef(false);
        const started = React.useRef(false);
        const DIMS = new Layout(104, 141, 21, 6 );
        let i = 0;
        const start = async () => {
            if (started.current) {return;};
            let done = 0;
            for (const element of inpdd) {
                console.log("Problem set "+element.problem_id);
                let inpda = new Array(element.algorithm);
                for (let j = 0; j < inpda.length; j++) {
                    console.log("Problem number "+j);
                    let probs = inpda[j].Problems;
                    for (const element of probs){
                        done = 0;
                        let pp = stuff.pg;
                        let PS_in = element.spec;
                        let PS = new ProbSpec(PS_in.free, PS_in.color, PS_in.shape, PS_in.size, PS_in.rotation);
                        // (algorithm, levels, depth, shapelimit, spec)
                        let PD = new ProbDef(element.algorithm, element.levels, element.depth, probs[j].shapelimit, PS);
                        console.log('PD is: ',PD);
                        let soln = problem(PD, pp, DIMS);
                        let problemRef = i+'_'+j;
                        while (done == 0) {
                            if (evaluateRef.current) {
                                evaluate(soln, pp, problemRef, DIMS);
                                while (!(continueRef.current)) {
                                    await sleep(10000);
                                }
                                done = 1;
                                pp.clear();
                                evaluateRef.current = false;
                                pp.data({'finalAnswer':-1});
                                break;
                            }
                            i++;
                            // console.log("time = "+i)
                            await sleep(1000);
                        }
                    }
        
                }
            }
        };
    
        return (
            <div style={{ display: "block"}}>
                <button type="button" onClick={() => {start();started.current = true; }}>Start</button>
                <button type="button" onClick={() => evaluateRef.current = true}>
                    Evaluate
                </button>
                <button type="button" onClick={() => continueRef.current = true}>
                    Continue
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    };
    ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
      .render(<RepeaterWithContinue />)

}
```

I tried putting in css styling to get it to explicitly show on the div container, no dice. I don't have any css offline, not sure if that is the solution.

Comment: Can you provide link to the website? Disable all plugins or open website in Incognito mode. Maybe some plugin is messing with the view.

Comment: The website is only available on a dev server, sorry.

Comment: Figured it out ... the buttons were showing up way at the bottom of the browser window initially. Inspect brought them into view.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.... the buttons appear way at the bottom of the page, scrolling down reveals them. This is clearly an initial formatting issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).